# In Android, how to launch device defalut slideshow activity?

Tags: android

My requirement is as follows,

1. Using camera activity capture a image and sore in an external storage card.
2. Show the captured images are in slide show.

Here i used default device camera intent to capture the image, and successfully stored in an sd card, the path is "sdcard/slideshow". Now i show the captured image in an slide show format. I searched how to load these images to the default (device in build slideshow) slideshow i won't get better result. Anyone have idea how to achieve this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you looked at [the Gallery widget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html)?

Comment: ya, but i need slide show, which means when i click a button or menu option it will launch and the image will move automatically with some fixed amount of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "device in build slideshow" in Android. You are welcome to find some third-party "slideshow" application, integrate with it, and recommend it to users. Or, you are welcome to build your own "slideshow" feature into your application.